# Flutter Init State Called Multiple Times

Tags: dart, flutter

Every time I navigate away from a widget, and then come back to it, I get a "n+1" call to the `initState` method of that widget.

The setup I have is something similar to this. I start at widget A, when a click on a Card is recognized, we do `Navigator.pushNamed(B.routeName)` to display the detail screen for this item. Once there is some additional processing done, the user clicks a "submit" button on B, and returns to a with `Navigator.pushNamed(A.routeName)`.

```
class A extends StatefulWidget {

  static String routeName = 'aroutename';
  A({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _AState createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSomeDataForScreenA().then((result) => setState(...));
  }

  whenDone(){

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(B.routeName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}

class B extends StatefulWidget {
  B({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _BState createState() => _BState();
}

class _BState extends State<B> {

  static String routeName = 'broutename';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSomeDataForScreenB().then((result) => setState(...));
  }

  whenDone(){
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(A.routeName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

The first time we see A, it's fine it only runs once. Then we go to B, and then once we return to A, initState() is called twice. The third time we make this cycle, it's called 3 times, etc...

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here as to what i am doing wrong. I am aware that this is probably due to a lack of understanding of the `Navigator.of(context)` inner workings, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: When done why not just use Navigator pop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem seems to have been with the way i was using the `flutter_redux` plugin. Not entirely sure what's caused it, but i'd imagine it's just forcing a duplicate state to be rendered because of how I was using it.

Long story short, I was storing the `active_tab` for the `BottomTab` in the redux state, not the local state for the `Home` screen container I had. The reason i did that in the first place was so that i could push a route onto home, and then also manipulate the tab that it was going to render as active first.

I think I will just refactor and use something like [Fluro](https://github.com/theyakka/fluro) here to allow me to pass arguments to my routes so that I can render a particular tab.

Hopefully if anyone else runs into this problem this helps, apologies in advance for not necessarily finding the underlying cause of why it was doing the re-render.

Answer (score 2):

`Navigator` works like a stack. It is used to push and pop "route". The top most route is visible.

This is what you are doing :

1. Route A is added to navigator stack. Stack : [A]
2. Route B is added to navigator stack. Stack : [A, B]
3. Route A is added to navigator stack. Stack : [A, B, A]
   ...

My guess is since routeName for all As and Bs in stack is same the state is reinstated.

What you should do is:
Pop B when done instead push A again.

whenDone should look like this:

```dart
whenDone(){
 Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this solves your problem. If not then let me know what issue you're having with it.

Comment: So i could do that, but the reason i was going with the "push" route was that i wanted init state to be run again (not twice but just once again on the reinitialization) so that the app could retrieve the most recent version of things that were potentially updated on Screen B.

Comment: I realize that this is a little bit wasteful in terms of network requests, but, it greatly simplifies the logic for making sure the local state of things matches the server side state of things.

Comment: I'm currently in the midst of using the VSCode step through debugger to try and determine why the (n + 1) of initState is happening. I'll keep this thread updated in the event that I can find it

Comment: give 'key: UniqueKey` to each route pushed, that might solve. it is some duplicate state problem.

Comment: if you look at my above explanation you'll see what fixed it. I'm not sure if that's clear. Do you have familiarity with the `flutter_redux` plugin?

Comment: I've no idea about redux

Comment: What would you do when you traverse more than one route, like `[A, B, C, [D], A]`? Use `popUntil`?

Comment: @KeithDC popUntil is what I do